# Install xgboost on PyCharm for beginners

Tags: python, xgboost

I am quite a beginner in Python, and this is my first time trying to install a library using pip.

I am trying to install xgboost library on PyCharm. I downloaded the package corresponding to the installed version of Python and bits from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

When I try to install the package using the command line 'pip install filemane.whl' I get this error: 'ERROR: xgboost-0.90-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.'

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: you have windows or linux? also 32-bit processor or 64-bit?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Mac, and I just got it from this page:

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/xgboost

The command I used that finally worked was:

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

After that it was available in my PyCharm virtual environment. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Back in my experience, a simple pip install xgboost worked. I was using ubuntu 16.04. My python and pip are from full anaconda 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu install globally and locally using following:

```
pip3 install xgboost
```